# How much notice should i give

Tags: interviewing, manager

I've worked for the same company for 12 years , I changed roles 6 months ago and this meant i still had to give the 1 months notice required before I changed departments .... now 6 months on I've got another job and I'm told it's still 1 months notice I'm required to serve ? Is this right ..I'd have thought with me serving a month before changing roles 6 months ago it would be the usual 1-2 week

Comment: What country are you in?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, It doesn't matter how long you've been in a specific department. What matters is how long you've been employed with the employer. In my home country, It's a months notice if you've been working for the same company for more than a year, irrespective of how many times you transfer within the company, although this may differ from country to country.

That said, the best answer for your question is written in your employment contract.  Refer to your employment contract or your local employment laws.

Answer (score 0):

Your contract of employment will be the arbiter of truth here.  I would expect it dictates a standard one month and doesn't consider edge-case scenarios such as having recently transferred to a different department.

I'd expect to work a month's notice but, if you are desperate to finish up sooner, you could ask if some arrangement could be reached which would allow you to complete just 2 weeks.  Perhaps agree to fully documenting your role, providing a thoroughly comprehensive handover to your replacement, work extra hours/weekends to deliver on commitments or even agree to make yourself available on call for an additional 2 weeks.

I don't know your reasons for leaving, but its rarely beneficial in the long run to burn your bridges. Whatever the notice period, work just as hard and conscientiously as you always have and leave them with a positive impression of you (even if you're not leaving with a positive one of them!)